# How to represent just space-character in replace string

Tags: macros

I want to replace space-character " " in a string with "-" using

`\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_marian_input_text_tl { <space-character-here> } { - }`
obviously `{ }` is not " "
i.e I want to change "A string" -> "A-string"

Comment: Space is represented by tilde `~` in `expl3` code (between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `expl3` code, a tilde `~` is used to represent space.

Note that repeated space characters in the input, as in `\inputtextB`, count as a single space, to be replaced by a single `-`. But the `\space` macro can be repeated:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}    
  \def\inputtextA{A String}
  \def\inputtextB{B  String}
  \edef\inputtextC{C\space\space String}

  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \inputtextA { ~ } { - }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \inputtextB { ~ } { - }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \inputtextC { ~ } { - }
  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \inputtextA

  \inputtextB

  \inputtextC
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I am stuck with "[" and "]"   .      Colon I have working using ``\tl_to_str:n { : }`` but that doesn't seem to work for "["

Comment: `\def\inputtextD{D]String}` and `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \inputtextD { ] } { - }` work for me.